How to remove the current user while fetching all the users from the database in react?
How can I use ternary operator (  ? true : false ) or something else to remove the currrent logged in user from this list?
    const [users,setUsers] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/bulk?filter=" + filter)
            .then(response => {
                setUsers(response.data.user)
            })
    }, [filter])
    
    // Then using it like this, to get all the users data.

    {users.map(user => <User key={user._id} user={user} />)}


I have tried using this, but in terms of seperating users. I didn't get it

You could more efficiently, apply the useMemo hook to remove the logged in user, rather than removing it at time of render


import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const UsersList = ({ filter }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const loggedInUserId = "someUserId"; // Replace with actual logged-in user ID

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/bulk?filter=${filter}`);
      setUsers(response.data.user);
    } catch (error) {
      setError("Error fetching users");
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, [filter]);

  const filteredUsers = useMemo(() => 
    users.filter(user => user._id !== loggedInUserId), [users, loggedInUserId]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredUsers.map(user => (
        <div key={user._id}>
          <h3>{user.name}</h3>
          {/* Add any other user data you'd like to display */}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsersList;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



Try it and comment if any doubts!!

I guess useMemo is a redundancy in this place as let us say this is used in a monitoring site and he wants all the user ID's and assuming in PROD you have new user sign-ups on a frequent basis, your useMemo makes no improvement here. Would stick to the solution that filters after fetch as that makes more sense. BTW this works, only the useMemo part might be redundant

@SARANSURYA ya, we use the useMemo() to eliminate repetitive heavy calculations.
I thought of doing that filter thing. One thing to note that I did was, I stored my token in the Authorization header using JWT. So, it have my userId as a field. But to extract the JWT token, in backend we use verify & extract it doing. What about doing it in react? or is there any other way. I think, I should fix the backend but quite confused.

@YashVarma well in that case you can make changes to the backend for a better reliability ? Maybe that works

Adding a filter at the backend is more useful if you have control over it. You could just simply exclude sending the user's data who requested the data, and that will be most efficient



  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  
  const loggedInUserId = "someUserId"; // Replace this with the actual logged-in user ID
  

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetching users from API
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/bulk?filter=" + filter)
      .then(response => {
        // Filter out the logged-in user from the response data
        const filteredUsers = response.data.user.filter(user => user._id !== loggedInUserId);
        setUsers(filteredUsers); // Update the state with filtered users
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
      });
  }, [filter, loggedInUserId]); // Depend on 'filter' and 'loggedInUserId' for re-fetching

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render users after filtering out the logged-in user */}
      {users.map(user => (
        <div key={user._id}>
          <h3>{user.name}</h3>
          {/* Add any other user data you'd like to display */}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




Hey, I thought of doing this. It's pretty decent solution. One things I did was, I stored my token in the Authorization header using JWT. So, it have my userId as a field. But to extract the JWT token, in backend we use verify & extract it doing. What about doing it in react? or is there any other way. I think, I should fix the backend but quite confused.
